# JQuery div height changed event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm making a website at http://harrisonprograms.com.

The design side of it is different to most sites, it also uses php and ajax to dynamically and asynchronously add comments, blog posts etc.

I use javascript to position the footer at the bottom of the page so when the page div extends it moves the footer further down the page by using the setTimeout function. However, this causes graphical glitches when scrolling up and down the page and if I set the time lower the footer lags.

So I want to know if there is any possible way I can monitor when the div has been resized to activate this function without using setTimeout to prevent these graphical glitches.

Comment: Have you considered using CSS to create a sticky footer?

Comment: Yes I have tried and it doesn't seem to work for me. I followed it step by step pretty much and it still doesn't work. Which is why I chose to use javascript.

Comment: I know it might take a bit to get it working ( wasn't really intuitive to me the first few times I made them) but using CSS is definitely the way to go if you want it to be as responsive as you've explained. I know css-tricks.com has some decent tutorials on it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use jQuery's resize event.

```
$(window).resize(function() {
  // resize your div here
});
```

Comment: I have tried this function before and I also researched it. It's a method that belongs to the window element and can't be used with other elements.

Comment: Typo, I did mean window. Are you seeing a performance flicker even if the event fires with the div doesn't resize?

Comment: What I mean is when the div itself resizes then I want to fire off my function called Repositioning which repositions the footer below the div element.

Comment: Is it possible for the div to resize without the window resizing?

Comment: Actually that's a good point let me test this code and I'll get back to you in a few minutes.

Comment: I have tested it and it only performs the function when the web browser itself has been resized and not the webpage. I wonder if you can do this with the document element as I believe this is the element for the page.

Comment: Ok, so something on the page is causing the whole page to get larger. Why not fire your event when whatever causes the page to get larger happens?

Comment: This is what I want to know but I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the help everyone but I found a a library that does what I need without graphical errors by Ben Alman check it out here if anyone needs help with this http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-resize-plugin/